# Visual Basic: If IP equals "String"

Tags: vb.net, ip, webclient, vpn

this is my first time coding, so excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to make a simple program that checks my IP, if my IP = "My Real IP", then it does an action. Basically I want to know when my VPN fails on me, and if it does, it'll take a certain arbitrary action.

```
Imports System.Net
Module Module1
Function GetIP() As String
    Dim YourIP As New WebClient
    Return YourIP.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/")
End Function

Sub Main()
    Console.Write(GetIP)
    If GetIP() = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Works")
    End If
End Sub 
End Module
```

I found someone with my exact same issue on here, and the solution was that DownloadString added "/n" to the end of the string and you had to basically do

```
GetIP().Replace("/n", "")
```

to remove it, but that solution did not work for me.

Comment: Try "\n" instead of "/n".

Comment: http://puu.sh/n4AU7/d426ed5685.png

Didn't work, and yes I changed the IP numbers to Xs before sending this.

Comment: Can you look at `Test` in a debugger and see exactly what's there?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea how ;-;

Comment: Ok I checked both, they both display my IP, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: Since this is VB.NET have you tried to replace the constant vbLf? At least that is appended to the ip when I tested your program.

Comment: Yes that was exactly it, thank you. How did you figure it out though? Just so I can know for next time. I tried debug.printing it and I just got my exact IP back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your program and found that although in a console application it looks like the IP generated by GetIP is just an IP, it is actually an IP with '& vbLf' tagged on the end.  This will mean that your comparison will always fail.

To remedy this, using String.Replace to remove the vbLf from the string generated by GetIP, like so:

```
 If GetIP().Replace(vbLf, String.Empty) = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Then
     Console.WriteLine("Works")
 End If
```

FYI, I found this by setting a variable to the result of GetIP() and inspecting it's contents during debugging.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I ended up using another method to remedy this issue, String.Contains. However, I did try to debug as best as I could. I did debug.print from GetIP, for another var set to GetIP, and I even exported GetIP to a text file. Everything just showed me IP, no extra letters. What did I do wrong, and how can I adequately debug next time? Again thanks a lot. I debugged as well as I could.

Comment: No worries - String.Contains will do the job in most cases - there is a possible problem if your IP is very close to the IP you're checking but I suppose that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: As far as debugging goes, vbLf is a special character which won't show up when using Debug.Print. The way I did it was to run the program in debug mode in visual studio and step over each line manually, hovering over my variable and inspecting it's contents after setting it to GetIP().

Answer (score 1):

Try this, rather than check your IP (which might change), Ping a known address like so....

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.co.uk", 1000) Then
            MsgBox("Server pinged successfully.")
        Else
            MsgBox("Ping request timed out.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Network is down.")
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Hope that help.....